# Concatenate variable and string in perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am saving a string in a variable. I want to use this variable in a regex along with some other patterns.

For example my variable is like this

```
my $value = 'COMPONENT'
```

I want to use this variable in regex along with some pattern like 01,02. So my matching expressions will be like

```
/COMPONENT01/
```

I am using something like this `/\Q$value/` But not sure how I can add 01 to it.

Comment: Reopened. None of the answers to the linked question answered the OP's question. All the answers suggested to use `\Q` or similar, so it was obviously a different question. I'm sure one could find a duplicate; this just wasn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\Q$value\E01/   # \E ends \Q
```

or

```
/\Q${value}01/   # Without the curlies, it would access var $value01
```